# Is 'for awhile' grammatical?

Tags: grammar

It appears to me that you can either say 'for a while' or 'awhile' because 'awhile' is an adverb and by itself means "for a while". Am I right? I'm asking it since I've seen 'for awhile' even in the Longman dictionary [here](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/awhile):

> - Once you power them up and get a topic, what you see is people can glide for **awhile** on that topic.
> - But if you rented a place to stay for **awhile** you would know.

Comment: A simple google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=while+vs+awhile+grammar&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&oq=while+vs+awhile+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.5905j0j7&hl=it&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @user070221 It doesn't answer the title question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, **for awhile** is incorrect. **while** is a noun, so it needs a preposition to attach it to a verb, but **awhile** is an adverb, so it doesn't need a preposition.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/awhile#usage-1) has this to say about it:

> **Can awhile be used after a preposition?: Usage Guide**
>   Although considered a solecism by many commentators, awhile, like several other adverbs of time and place, is often used as the object of a preposition.
>   *… would be generous enough to let me explore their world for awhile.*  — David Yeadon

This [Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for%20awhile%3A%20eng_gb_2012%2Cawhile%3A%20eng_gb_2012%2Cawhile%3A%20eng_us_2012%2Cfor%20awhile%3A%20eng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20awhile%3A%20eng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cawhile%3A%20eng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cawhile%3A%20eng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20awhile%3A%20eng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0) shows that **awhile** was as common in the UK as in the US a hundred years ago, but since 1960 it has declined in the UK but increased in the US. **for awhile** is currently a lot more common in American English than British English, but this may simply be because **awhile** is generally more common in the US.

Combining words that traditionally were separate is more common in American English, for example **[anymore](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/anymore)**. As this [Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anymore%3A%20eng_gb_2012%2Canymore%3A%20eng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canymore%3A%20eng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canymore%3A%20eng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0) shows, the usage in both countries has increased dramatically since 1960.

I have also seen **alot** (meaning **a lot**) in private correspondence, but cannot find any reference to this in UK or US dictionaries.